# Translating Structure Map into Autofac

Tags: silverlight, dependency-injection, structuremap, autofac

I have recently puchased a very good book on MVVM - MVVM Survival Guide For Enterprise Architectures in Silverlight and WPF

Unfortunatly, one of the sections relating to IoC has a lot of code samples for StructureMap which is not available for Silverlight

Can anyone point me to a link that would help me translate Structure Map code to Autofac which is the injection tool I am looking at using

The code uses the factory mehod of creating classes and a bootstrapper

```
using Northwind.ViewModel;
using StructureMap;

namespace Northwind.UI.WPF
{
    public class BootStrapper
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return ObjectFactory
                    .GetInstance<MainWindowViewModel>();
            }
        }

        public BootStrapper()
        {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(
                o => o.Scan(
                    a =>
                    {
                        a.WithDefaultConventions();
                        a.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(
                            d => d.FullName
                                .StartsWith("Northwind"));
                        a.LookForRegistries();
                    }));
        }
    }


    using StructureMap;

    namespace Northwind.ViewModel
    {
    public class CustomerDetailsViewModelFactory 
        : ICustomerDetailsViewModelFactory
    {
        private readonly IContainer _container;

        public CustomerDetailsViewModelFactory(
            IContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public CustomerDetailsViewModel CreateInstance(
            string customerID)
        {
            return _container
                .With("customerID")
                .EqualTo(customerID)
                .GetInstance<CustomerDetailsViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Autofac and StructureMap work differently, so you can't "translate" it one to one.
However, **this is what it should look like** to accomplish the same.
I've made some assumptions as not everything is there to test out your code.

```
public class BootStrapper
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _container;

    public BootStrapper()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        Assembly[] assemblies =
            GetAssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(
                x => x.FullName.StartsWith("Northwind"));

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
               .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        // Module in Autofac = Registry in StructureMap
        builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assemblies);

        Assembly viewModelAssembly =
            typeof(MainWindowViewModel).Assembly;

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(viewModelAssembly);

        _container = builder.Build();
    }

    private static Assembly[] GetAssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(Func<AssemblyName, bool> condition)
    {
        string baseDirectoryPath =
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        Func<string, bool> isAssembly =
            file => string.Equals(
                Path.GetExtension(file), ".dll", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        return Directory.GetFiles(baseDirectoryPath)
                        .Where(isAssembly)
                        .Where(f => condition(new AssemblyName(f)))
                        .Select(Assembly.LoadFrom)
                        .ToArray();
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _container.Resolve<MainWindowViewModel>();
        }
    }
}

public class CustomerDetailsViewModelFactory : ICustomerDetailsViewModelFactory
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _container;

    public CustomerDetailsViewModelFactory(ILifetimeScope container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public CustomerDetailsViewModel CreateInstance(string customerID)
    {
        return _container.Resolve<CustomerDetailsViewModel>(
                new NamedParameter("customerID", customerID));
    }
}
```