# Register Assembly Modules from Base Folder

Tags: c#, autofac

I have WinForms project thats has 2 references to Assemblies I want to remove. There are only there because in need them in Bootstrap to do a typeof in the registration of Modules.

```
  var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

  var AssemblyCore = typeof (Fle.SQLServer.Core.Impl.Checker.Registry).Assembly;
  builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(AssemblyCore);

  var AssemblyXml = typeof (Fle.SQLServer.XmlFiles.Registry).Assembly;
  builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(AssemblyXml);
```

[image]

Structure map has something that is called AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory does autofac has the same or something similar? Or can i register a RegisterAsseblyModels with path?

Answer (score 2):

If Assemblies are not referenced in the project, one option is to Load the assemblies from the directory and then Register them with `Autofac` builder as shown below. Below example is not a complete example. It just demonstrates the possible solution of the original problem.

```
public class BootStrapper
{
    public BootStrapper()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        Assembly[] assemblies =
            GetAssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(
                x => x.FullName.StartsWith("Fle.SQLServer"));

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
               .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assemblies);
    }
    private static Assembly[] GetAssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(Func<AssemblyName, bool> condition)
    {
        string baseDirectoryPath =
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        Func<string, bool> isAssembly =
            file => string.Equals(
                Path.GetExtension(file), ".dll", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        return Directory.GetFiles(baseDirectoryPath)
                        .Where(isAssembly)
                        .Where(f => condition(new AssemblyName(f)))
                        .Select(Assembly.LoadFrom)
                        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Reference: [translating-structure-map-into-autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090569/translating-structure-map-into-autofac)